# how to properly format stack trace information in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, stack-trace

I have asp.net core's layered architecture something like code below.

[image]

and the main function (API controller) is calling the GrandParent method and controller function also has the try-catch block. for example, an exception occurs in GetNumber function. the exception will bubble-up to the controller. Now if i see the stack trace i can see the trace from Controller->Grandparent->Parent->GetNumber.

is there a way to beautify this stack trace in a way that can tell me this entire stack of calls with just their function names and line number where the original exception occurred, so that I can simply log that formatted beautified information instead of logging the original stack trace?

Is there something Asp.net core gives out of the box for such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like (i dont know how exactly you want format those)

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
stackTrace.GetFrames().Select(f => $"{f.GetMethod()} {f.GetFileLineNumber()}");
```